# How can I access the table comment from a mysql table?

Tags: mysql, comments

How can I get *just* the table comment from a mysql table?  I tried the following, but they didn't work for various reasons.  I want to figure out how to get just the string 'my comment' (ideally via perl =)

Any help?

```
-- Abbreviated output for convenience.
SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE Name="foo"
+------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+---------------+
| Name | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows | Create_options | Comment       |
+------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+---------------+
| foo  | MyISAM |      10 | Fixed      |    0 |                | my comment    | 
+------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+---------------+
```

and

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE foo;
+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table | Create Table                                                                 |
+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| fooo  | CREATE TABLE `fooo` (`id` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY) COMMENT='my comment' | 
+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Based on the answer by *OMG Ponies*, but using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` instead of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`.  When looking around on the web, all I could find was info on the columns' comments, but never on the table's.  This is how to get a *table's* comment.

```sql
SELECT table_comment 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
    WHERE table_schema='my_cool_database' 
        AND table_name='user_skill';
```

```
+--------------------------+
| table_comment            |
+--------------------------+
| my awesome comment       | 
+--------------------------+
```

Answer (score 11):

If you don't want to have both database name and table name in the query, you can use :

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE Name='table_name';
```

and then pick up the "Comment" key of the result (you have to use an associative function like mysqli_fetch_assoc() in php).